# How exactly works the AngularJS application component (module, factory, controller) definition?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, javascript-objects, angularjs-controller, angularjs-factory

I am absolutley new in AngularJS and pretty new in JavaScript and I have the following doubt related to this example showed into a tutorial:

```
// Creates values or objects on demand
angular.module("myApp")     // Get the "myApp" module created into the root.js file (into this module is injected the "serviceModule" service
.value("testValue", "AngularJS Udemy")

// Define a factory named "courseFactory" in which is injected the testValue
.factory("courseFactory", function(testValue) {
    // The factory create a "courseFactory" JSON object;
    var courseFactory = {
            'courseName': testValue,    // Injected value
            'author': 'Tuna Tore',
             getCourse: function(){     // A function is a valid field of a JSON object
             alert('Course: ' + this.courseName);   // Also the call of another function
            }
          };    
    return courseFactory;       // Return the created JSON object
})

// Controller named "factoryController" in which is injected the $scope service and the "courseFactory" factory:
.controller("factoryController", function($scope, courseFactory) {
    alert(courseFactory.courseName);        // When the view is shown first show a popupr retrieving the courseName form the factory
    $scope.courseName = courseFactory.courseName;
    console.log(courseFactory.courseName);
    courseFactory.getCourse();  // Cause the second alert message
});
```

It is pretty clear for me what it done: it create an angular module that represent my application and that is named **myApp**. then define a value, a factory (that return a **courseFactory** JSON object) and finally a controller in which the previous factory is injected.

The think that it is not clear for me is the syntax of the declaration of these "components".

So, it seems me, that the "syntax" is something like this:

```
angular.module("myApp").value(VALUE DECLARATION).factory("courseFactory", function(testValue) { RETURN THE JSON OBJECT IMPLEMENTING THE FACTORY }).controller("factoryController", function($scope, courseFactory) { IMPLEMENT THE CONTROLLER });
```

So my doubt is: why all the "components" (the **value** declaration, the **factory** implementation and the **controller** implementation) are defined in a "concatentaion chain" where the "." symbol add these component to the chain?

What exactly mean this "." ?

I think that it add a field to an object or something like this but it seems strange to me.

So first there is the **angular** object (is it an object or what?) on which is added the **module("myApp")** "component" (and it seems logic because I am adding a module to Angular).

Then a **value** is added as property of this **module**. And also it seems to make sense because I am adding a **value** to a specific **module**.

But why then a **factory** s added as field of this **value** and then the **controller** is added as a field of this **factory**?

I think that I am missing something.

What am I missing? How ezactly work the AngularJS "component" definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following:

```
angular.module("myApp")
```

Will return the object that represents the module.

You can inspect this by doing:

```
console.log(angular.module("myApp"));
```

You will see that this object has a bunch of methods, for example `value`, `controller` and `factory`.

This explains why you can do the following:

```
angular.module("myApp").value("testValue", "AngularJS Udemy");
```

The trick is that the value method also returns the module object so you can continue the chain:

```
angular.module("myApp").value("testValue", "AngularJS Udemy").factory(...)
```

The same goes for the other methods on the module object.

Having methods returning the main object like this is a common technique to allow this kind of chaining.

You can read it like this:

```
var myModule;

myModule = angular.module('myApp'); // Returns the module

myModule = myModule.value(...); // Registers a value and returns the module

myModule = myModule.factory(...); // Registers a factory and returns the module
```